# Laravel: How can I write a policy class for API methods on a nested resource controller?

Tags: laravel, rest, model, nested-resources

I have a many to many relationship that I'm working with between `User` and `Task` models. A user belongs to many tasks and a task belongs to many users. I have a pivot table called `task_user`.

In my API, I have a route defined as follows:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}/tasks', 'TaskUserController@all');
```

I want to write a policy to enforce that the currently logged in user, `auth()->user`, is the user being requested in the route. Basically, a user can only view their own tasks.

How can I write a policy class for the nested resource controller `TaskUserController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting of your resource has nothing to do with making policies.

Make your UserPolicy.

```
class UserPolicy()
{
    public function view(User $authorizedUser, User $user) {
        return $authorizedUser->is($user);
    }
}
```

In your controller, you can authorize the action, with the `authorize()` helper. Alternatively it can be executed in your form request with `Auth::user()->can()`.

```
class TaskController {
    public function all(User $user)) {
        $this->authorize('view', $user);

        return $user->tasks;
    }
}
```